# Can a page post on another page's wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

Using FQL, I want to get the posts on a page's wall. Each one of these posts hasa an actor_id. Can I assume that all the actor_id's are either users or the owning page's id?
This assumption would be false if another page could post on this page's wall.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a page can post on another page's wall. If you have a Facebook page (which is NOT an application profile page) then you can click the arrow in the upper-right UI of Facebook and say "Use Facebook as a Page", select your page, and you will be "logged in" as that page. Pages can Like other pages, post on their walls, and comment, but they can't participate in apps or post to individual users.

Use that to test the scenario where one page posts to another.